# Sum rows from the join table sq

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have a query that I join the result from different views like this.

```
select ip.product_no, ip.description, ac.description,op.operation_no,op.sale_qty, ip.contract, ro.work_center_n, ipp.mul_order_qty as "Qty/box"

from product ip
join accounting_group ac on ip.acc_group = ac.acc_group
join routing_operation ro on ip.product_no= ro.product_noand ip.contract = ro.contract
join INVEN_PLANNING ipp on ip.product_no= ipp.product_noand ip.contract = ipp.contract
join OPER_STATISTIC op on ip.product_no= op.product_no
where ro.center_no like '%'
and ip.product_no like '%'
```

And this query got me the result like this:

```
product_no = desc == ac.des = operation_no = sale_qty= contract = work_center_no = "Qty/box"  
12121        clothes   finish     1           20             US           7               15
12121        clothes   finish     2           10             US           7               15
12123        clothes   finish     1           20             US           7               15
12123        clothes   finish     2           20             US           7               15
12124        clothes   finish     1           20             US           7               15
12124        clothes   finish     2           20             US           7               15
12125        clothes   finish     3           20             US           7               15
```

How can I sum report_qty then? The expected result will be like this:

```
 product_no = desc == ac.des  = SUM(sale_qty)= contract = work_center_no = "Qty/box"  
 12121      clothes   finish         40           US           7             15
 12123      clothes   finish         40           US           7             15
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for aggregation:

```
select 
    ip.product_no, 
    ip.description, 
    ac.description,
    sum(op.sale_qty) sum_sale_qty,
    ip.contract, 
    ipp.mul_order_qty as "Qty/box"
from product ip
join accounting_group ac on ip.acc_group = ac.acc_group
join routing_operation ro on ip.product_no= ro.product_no and ip.contract = ro.contract
join INVEN_PLANNING ipp on ip.product_no= ipp.product_no and ip.contract = ipp.contract
join OPER_STATISTIC op on ip.product_no= op.product_no
where ro.center_no like '%' and ip.product_no like '%'
group by 
    ip.product_no, 
    ip.description, 
    ac.description,
    ip.contract, 
    ipp.mul_order_qty
```

NB: the `where` clause is a bit weird:

```
where ro.center_no like '%' and ip.product_no like '%'
```

This can be optimized as follows (which would allow the use of an index):

```
where ro.center_no is not null and ip.product_no is not null
```

Also, since `ip.product_no` is used in an `inner join` condition, we know that it's not null, so this boils down to:

```
where ro.center_no is not null
```